# How to skip over HTTPError 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, scripting, http-error

I have been trying to write a Python script that downloads images from URLs in a script. There are about 1400 URLs to open and not all of them are existing and some need special access to open them. With the script that is written below, I wanted the script only to open URLs with an HTTP response of 200 (OK) and to skip URLs with different responses. But for some reason, HTTPError 403 still keeps popping up when running the script and kills the downloading process.

Can someone help me to make sure that HTTPError 403 (and other errors) are not affecting the script while it's running?
(I added a sleep function in case the script would stop due to too many continuous requests.)

```
with open('images.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
next(csv_reader)
RQs = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    basename = os.path.basename(urlparse(row[0]).path)
    filename = '{}/{}/{}'.format(row[2], row[1], basename)

    if RQs == 200:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("sleeping for 5 seconds")
        RQs = 0

    response = requests.get(row[0])
    if response.status_code == 200: #could also check == requests.codes.ok
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(row[0], filename)
    else:
        continue
    RQs += 1
```

Comment: Do you use (external) `requests` library for checking status and (built-in) `urllib` for file retrieval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by doing:

```
response = requests.get(row[0])
if response.status_code == 200: #could also check == requests.codes.ok
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(row[0], filename)
```

You are launching 2 different requests, second might result in `403` even if first result in `200`, for example when site do forbid access based on User-Agent. To avoid this and avoid superfluous double request, you can do:

```
response = requests.get(row[0])
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

This way you will get your file (`response.content` is just content as bytes, so I use write-binary mode) from already done request rather than launching next one, which might fail.